# Developing MicroServices using spring boot

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to develop microservice using spring boot+jpa +hibernate. But each time when I run my code, it creates by default 10 connection with the Database (postgresql). I configured my application.yml but still it didn't over-ride the datasource properties. Can anybody help me to get out of this?

```
spring:
    dataSource:
        tomcat:
             max-active: 5
             max-idle: 5
             min-idle: 5
             initial-size: 5
             commitOnReturn: True
             maxAge: 300000
             min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 20000
             max-threads: 10
             validation-query: SELECT 1
             test-on-borrow: true
             validation-interval: 300000
```

Here,I am going to add my GetApp.java class.check this:

```
package com.pwc.nic.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.
DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
```

import
 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = {

```
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
},
scanBasePackages = { "com.pwc.nic" })
```

public class GetApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GetApp.class, args);
}
```

}

Comment: I guess you are configuring the wrong datasource. why is it namend spring.datasource.tomcat and not spring.datasource.hikari?

Comment: But @SimonMartinelli datasource used by me is by tomcat not hikari.That's why I used above configuration.Revert back in case of any doubt.

Comment: I suspect that tomcat data source is not getting used. Explicitly set the data source using configuration: spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource and try again

Comment: but if you use the tomcat datasource you have to configure it in tomcat configuratoin not in Spring Boot

Comment: @Ajinkya As per your suggestion I used spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource in my application.yml file but it didn't worked.Yet no. of connection is 10.

Answer (score 0):

As per spring boot documentation, you should be using spring.datasource.max-active property. See here 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Also as per tomcat documentation you should try initialSize attribute which says initial number of connections that are made when pool is created. See here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes

Comment: thanks for replying .But I already used max-active property but still it always create 10 new connection each time.

Comment: I think you should try initialSize attribute which says initial number of connections that are made when pool is created. See here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes